# Need to ID states from mixed names /IDs in location data

Tags: r

Need to ID states from mixed location data
Need to search for 50 states abbreviations & 50 states full names, and return state abbreviation

```
N <- 1:10
Loc <- c("Los Angeles, CA", "Manhattan, NY", "Florida, USA", "Chicago, IL" , "Houston, TX",
+           "Texas, USA", "Corona, CA", "Georgia, USA", "WV NY NJ", "qwerty uy PO DOPL JKF" )
df <- data.frame(N, Loc)
> # Objective create variable state such 
> # state contains abbreviated names of states from Loc: 
> # for "Los Angeles, CA", state = CA
> # for "Florida, USA", sate = FL
> # for "WV NY NJ", state = NA
> # for "qwerty NJuy PO DOPL JKF", sate = NA (inspite of containing the srting NJ, it is not wrapped in spaces)
> 
# End result should be Newdf
State <- c("CA", "NY", "FL", "IL", "TX","TX", "CA", "GA", NA, NA)
Newdf <- data.frame(N, Loc, State)
> Newdf
    N                   Loc State
1   1       Los Angeles, CA    CA
2   2         Manhattan, NY    NY
3   3          Florida, USA    FL
4   4           Chicago, IL    IL
5   5           Houston, TX    TX
6   6            Texas, USA    TX
7   7            Corona, CA    CA
8   8          Georgia, USA    GA
9   9              WV NY NJ  <NA>
10 10 qwerty uy PO DOPL JKF  <NA>
```

Is there a package? or can a loop be written? Even if the schema could be demonstrated with a few states, that would be sufficient - I will post the full solution when I get to it. Btw, this is for a Twitter dataset downloaded using rtweet package, and the variable is: `place_full_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilising the built-in R constants, `state.abb` and `state.name`, we can try to extract these from the `Loc` with regular expressions.

```
state.abbs <- sub('.+, ([A-Z]{2})', '\\1', df$Loc)
state.names <- sub('^(.+),.+', '\\1', df$Loc)
```

Now `if` the state abbreviations are not in any of the built-in ones, then we can use `match` to find the positions of our `state.names` that are in any of the items in the built-in `state.name` vector, and use that to index `state.abb`, `else` keep what we already have. Those that don't match either return NA.

```
df$state.abb <- ifelse(!state.abbs %in% state.abb, 
                       state.abb[match(state.names, state.name)], state.abbs)
df
    N                   Loc state.abb
1   1       Los Angeles, CA        CA
2   2         Manhattan, NY        NY
3   3          Florida, USA        FL
4   4           Chicago, IL        IL
5   5           Houston, TX        TX
6   6            Texas, USA        TX
7   7            Corona, CA        CA
8   8          Georgia, USA        GA
9   9              WV NY NJ      <NA>
10 10 qwerty uy PO DOPL JKF      <NA>
```

Comment: Perfect, accepted - thank you!  Also tried more combinations of text including state names mixed with non-aligned abbreviations etc; - works in all cases tried so far!

Answer (score 1):

There are default constants in R, `state.abb` and `state.name` which can be used.

```
vars <-  stringr::str_extract(df$Loc, paste0('\\b',c(state.abb, state.name), 
                                             '\\b', collapse = '|'))
#[1] "CA"  "NY"  "Florida" "IL" "TX"  "Texas"  "CA" "Georgia" "WV"      NA
```

If you want everything as abbreviations, we can go further and do :

```
inds <- vars %in% state.name
vars[inds] <- state.abb[match(vars[inds], state.name)]
vars
#[1] "CA" "NY" "FL" "IL" "TX" "TX" "CA" "GA" "WV" NA
```

However, we can see that in 9th row you expect output as `NA` but here it returns `"WV"` because it is a state name. In such cases, you need to prepare rules which are strict enough so that it only extracts state names and nothing else.

Comment: `state.abb, state.name` approach is ideal - useful & voted +, Edwards's solution below is a comprehensive solution though. Thx!